# SQL Query Combine Rows on ID

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to run a query on my quote history table and trying to get an understanding of our response time.

I have a table named status_history and I wish to return the date difference between two rows for the same quote.

I  have the following query:

```
SELECT
    quote_number,
    status,
    date,
    DATEDIFF
    (hh,
    (SELECT dateEntered 
            FROM status_history 
            WHERE status = 'Submitted'),
    (SELECT dateEntered 
            FROM status_history 
            WHERE status = 'Accepted')) as hour_difference

FROM 
    status_history

WHERE 
    status in ('Submitted','Accepted')
```

I am trying to get the final query to output like this:

```
quote_number| hour_difference
```

I am having a hard time getting this to output the way I want, because each quoteid can have multiple rows, because it can have a status change multiple times.  Like seen here:

```
quote_number |  status     |  date
---------------------------------------------------
1234         | Submitted   |  2014-05-12 00:00:00.000
1234         | Accepted    |  2014-05-13 00:00:00.000
1234         | Complete    |  2014-05-14 00:00:00.000
1234         | Incomplete  |  2014-05-15 00:00:00.000
```

Eventually, I would like to check for the time between all status changes, but just this for now should get me going.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT quote_number, 
       DATEDIFF(hh,
                max(case when status = 'Submitted' then dateEntered end),
                max(case when status = 'Accepted' then dateEntered end)
               ) as hour_difference
FROM status_history
WHERE status in ('Submitted','Accepted')
GROUP BY quote_number;
```

Comment: this is almost exactly what I want!  Thanks - is there any way to remove the rows that return NULL for hour_difference?  Also, is it possible to also have the time from the status = 'Accepted' to 'Bound'?

Comment: Don't worry about it, I am just going to make several stored procedures to take care of the same thing.